# How to disable default keyboard shortcuts in Kendo UI?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

How can I disable default shortcuts like arrow up / arrow down in kendoNumericTextBox? By default this controll increment/decrement value then push up/down arrow. I cant find the way to disable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is much easier way, just set step:0

```
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    step:0
});
```

Comment: This works great- it does prevent value change with key press.  However one side effect is that if the value was blank/null, it does replace it with '0', which was undesirable in our case.  For that situation the other answer to unbind the event is a more complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable arrow up and down keyboard shortcuts by [unbinding the "keydown" event handler](http://jsbin.com/revuxiweji/edit?html,js,output):

```
<input id="ntbox" />

<script>
    $("#ntbox").kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox").element.unbind("keydown");
</script>
```

Also arrow up and arrow down on the widget can be disabled if they are not rendered, the widget is readonly or disabled.

```
<input id="ntbox1" />
<input id="ntbox2" />
<input id="ntbox3" disabled="disabled" />

<script>
    // Hidden spin buttons: the up and down spin buttons are not rendered.
    $("#ntbox1").kendoNumericTextBox({ spinners: false });

    // Read-only widget: when the widget is readonly it doesn't allow user input.
    $("#ntbox2").kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox").readonly();

    // Disabled widget: the value of a disabled widget is not posted as part of a form.
    $("#ntbox3").kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox").enable(false);
</script>
```